# Resolving an IntId

Tags: python, plone, dexterity

I am passing an IntId of Dexterity content through a form into a browser view.
How can I resolve the IntId back into the original object in Plone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `IIntIds` utility:

```
from zope.component import getUtility
from zope.intid.interfaces import IIntIds

intidutil = getUtility(IIntIds)
object = intidutil.getObject(id)
```

Alternatively, you could use the `.queryObject()` method, it takes a `default` keyword parameter (defaults to `None`), returned if the id is not found.